# Magento: include and app/code/core from another location(above webroot)

Tags: magento

I am looking for a way to include magentos app/code/core from above webroot.

It is no problem to do this with /lib, just add the path at the end of the include path in your php.ini

Something like
.:/existing/path:/home/yourdomain/magento/lib

For demo-stores or development servers this means saving 30mb or more than 3000 files per installation.

Therefore I would love to do the same with app/code/core as it is another 26mb and more than 5000 files per installation.

Did open a thread here
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/457181/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this...

Modify app/Mage.php where you will find the following lines that add paths to check when you include files...

```
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

$appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
```

You could change BP to wherever you move the code, or change these entirely.

If you move the entire app directory, then change your index.php file in your web base directory. You'll see this line

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

You'll want to change this to wherever you moved it. `Mage.php` is what bootstraps the whole operation.